# Automatic simplification of trigonometric functions with negative arguments

Tags: evaluation, trigonometry, calculus-and-analysis

I'm fairly new to mathematica and its ability to define *pure* functions. I was using it to work on a school problem. The idea was to derive a vector with two trig functions that I could set another function to and repeat this process once more.

```
r[t_] := {Cos[-t], Sin[-t], 4t}
```

Just simply plugging in `t` for the function provides an incorrect output.

```
r[t] == {Cos[t],Sin[t],4t}
```

Which is incorrect. I am almost thinking that this is some property of *Mathematica* always converting the variable I input as a negative radian. However when I go to proceed with setting a new function to the derivative of the old one this 'lost' negative affects my derivative.

```
v[t_] := r'[t]
```

With this is mind it should equal:

```
v[t] == {Sin[-t],-Cos[-t],4}
```

However when I input this it I get

```
v[t] == {-Sin[t], -Cos[t], 4}
```

How do I go about solving this problem. I've tried some of the debugging lines such a Trace but cant seem to come up with why this doesn't work.

Comment: After defining `r[t_] := {Cos[-t], Sin[-t], 4 t}` I type r[t] and get: `{Cos[t], -Sin[t], 4 t}` which is correct.

Comment: @bills Why is this correct? I'm assuming its utilizing trig identities but technically I would assume the output of r[t] should be {Cos[-t],Sin[-t],4t}

Comment: Further, `{-Sin[t], -Cos[t], 4} == {Sin[-t], -Cos[-t], 4}` gives True so the operations with v[t] are correct as well.

Comment: Some rules are automatically applied.  See "Properties & Relations" in the documentation for `Sin`.

Comment: So is their anyway i can prevent mathematica from simplifying the original form? Although it seems negligible i cannot have it do this reduction.

Comment: `Hold[Sin[-x]]` or `HoldForm[Sin[-x]]`...but that's hardly helpful, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks guys you helped solve my issue on here I'm just getting a wrong answer still with my online grading system, must mean i have a fault in my formula or they have a fault in their answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These simplifications are happening because

```
Cos[t] == Cos[-t]
True
Sin[t] == -Sin[-t]
True
```

In words, Cosine is an even function and Sin is an odd function. Trying to fight the automated simplifications is like trying to ask Mathematica to *not* simplify `x*x` into `x^2` or `x+2*x` into `3 x`. These occur because Mathematica is a pattern rewrite language, not a procedural language (in which it executes steps in order like a recipe). Whenever Mathematica is presented with an input, it tries to change its form using all its available rules.

Comment: That makes total sense, coming from different programming languages this is the first time I've seen a function reduced without telling the program to do so. I understand it but nevertheless find it interesting.

Answer (score 3):

This is as close as I can come.  As [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s) implies, since the rules are applied internally and automatically, it seems a bit like fighting the tide.

```
Block[{Sin, Cos},
 HoldForm[#] &@v[t]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{Sin = Inactive[Sin], Cos = Inactive[Cos]},
 HoldForm[#] &@v[t]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This definitely works for getting the form to hold and for whatever reason im still getting an incorrect answer leading me to believe it is either a fault in my formula or the online grading system.